# How to remove screw from broken threaded insert?

Tags: screws, rust

I don't want to destroy either part since I plan to try to reuse them. I have applied WD40. I tried to use pliers to rotate them (you can see the scratch marks). Nothing. It is like they are welded together.
[image: Picture]

This is how a normal one looks like
[image]

Comment: Try heating the part, then try to unscrew while still hot.

Comment: Sometimes WD-40 is not good enough, might need a better penetrating oil.  Most basic hand pliers  will not have enough bite, a good pair of locking pliers or a pipe wrench will bite into and hold better.

Comment: WD-40 is for displacing water. It is NOT a penetrating oil. PB-Blaster, Kroil and probably some others are actual penetrating oils. ATF mixed with tolulene is a home-made one.

Comment: @Ecnerwal  I have heard that ATF and acetone is one of the best.  Have not heard of toluene.

Comment: I think I've seen various solvents combined with it, as might happen with it being a "home-brew" recipe.

Comment: WD-40 is a lubricating & penetrating oil. This myth that it isn't is rather persistent though. From the horse's mouth - https://www.wd40.com/myths-legends-fun-facts/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used a rotary tool with cutting disc to go around the point where the screw and threaded insert meet and striped ~1x1 mm of metal all around. That released the screw and it was free to rotate.

Comment: Thanks for posting your solution. Be sure to accept your answer. You may want to reconsider reusing this insert. Whatever caused it to jam the first time may repeat itself and you may not be able to extract the screw next time around. Also, now that you've cut into the screw or insert, they may not hold together as they did before and it could fail unexpectedly.

Comment: In 2 days! The screw thread is 4 mm long and the threads on the insert go all the way down. I used two part epoxy for metal to glue the insert back. The screw has the same number of twists as normal one and I think it will hold. I hope.